# Background in capybara tests using cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

Learning new Rails application and writing some tests for it. While writing tests, question came across is :

What is the meaning of writing 'Background' in capybara tests using cucumber? Why do we write 'Background' at all? Can it be avoided?

-> Does it have anything to do with the test database? Or Does it serve as the database for the "Scenario"?

```
Feature: User signup
  As a user
  I want to sign in
  So I can use service features

**Background**:
  Given user with "jack@daniles.com" email and "qwerty" password

Scenario: Signing in with correct credentials
  When I go to sign in page
  And I fill in "email" with "jack@daniles.com"
  And I fill in "password" with "qwerty"
  And I click "Login" button
  Then I should see "Welcome, jack@daniles.com!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background is run before each of your scenarios but after any of your Before Hooks.
Its DRY strategy for writing cucumber scenarios. A set of "prerequisite" steps that should be executed before running actual test case.

For eg. Before checking a Dashboard or profile page contents a user must be logged in. So, logged in coverage will be done inside "Background" section
Then you will have 2 test cases

Background:
// Get user logged-in

Scenario : //Visit Dashboard Page .....

Scenario: //Visit Profile Page ....

For more info https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background

For different set of users you can use Scenario Outline 
Here is example:

https://makandracards.com/makandra/18905-how-to-not-repeat-yourself-in-cucumber-scenarios

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

The point of Background is to define a common starting point for several scenarios. If you only have one scenario it only makes sense as a means of dividing things into parts. If you are familiar with unit test frameworks it is similar to the setup method in the xunit family, or a before block if you use rspec. For the purpose of running the test the stuff in *background* could just as well be inside the scenario. It is a mechanism for reuse.

There is no direct relation between *background* and the test database. All the steps you run from cucumber may hit the database. The *background* is used to set up a good starting state in the database. Depending on your cucumber/capybara config the database will be reset between each scenario and the backgroun run again before each scenario.

Comment: Thanks for writing it up. Question now is :

What if I write different name/email in Background and different in Scenario? I am not also able to catch the relation between Background and scenario.

Comment: Try to think of the background as steps that is executed before the scenario. If you can't see a relation then maybe you can remove it? In your example above the idea is to set up your database with a specific user that can be reused between scenarios.